# Calling this BuyProductID in iOS purchase page showling slow?

Tags: unity-game-engine

why i calling this BuyProductID (m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product)) ios show the purchase page is slow? it 's take more time then other game.
here is my code

````
void BuyProductID(string productId)
   {
       if (IsInitialized())
       {
           UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

           if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
           {

               m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
           }
           else
           {
               MyDebug("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
           }
       }
       else
       {
           MyDebug("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
       }
   } ```


any ideas?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use sandbox to test it

Apple's sandbox service can be slow, the live server should be much quicker.